# Enlace HTML no se abre

Tags: html

Debido a que quiero que el enlace se abra en la misma pestaña, no he añadido ningún target, ya que se supone que "_self" es el que viene por defecto. No obstante, solo con este código, no abre ningún enlace:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Abre</h1>
    <a href="www.youtube.com" >YT</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

He probado a poner `onclick="window.open(this.href)"` después del enlace, pero ello no ha solucionado el problema. Sé que el problema no es del enlace en sí ya que, de poner `target="_blank"` sí se abre. El problema es que de esta manera se abre en otra pestaña y a mi me gustaría que lo hiciera en la misma. ¿Qué puedo hacer para que el link se abra y lo haga en la misma pestaña?

Comment: Añade la url completa de Youtube, que en este caso tiene https: https://www.youtube.com

Comment: @GDP la próxima vez que edites, es mejor no modificar el código directamente en su mensaje, hazlo a través de una respuesta, si no quien venga detrás a leerlo seguramente no entienda las respuestas porque no verá el cambio :)

Comment: @GDP: No deben realizarse ediciones que cambien el sentido original de la pregunta, en este caso específico, si el problema es que no abre el enlace, no debe cambiarse el enlace. Por lo anterior he revertido la edición.

Comment: pepito: Cuando un código no funciona debe indicarse el mensaje de error de forma textual. Mas detalles en [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

Agrégale el protocolo `http://` al enlace.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Abre</h1>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com" >YT</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hay que agregarle el protocolo `http` o `https` porque sin él, la URL estaba funcionando como una URL relativa, adjuntando la cadena `www.youtube.com` a la URL que tenga el navegador, de tal modo que si estamos en http://localhost el resultado del click nos estaba redirigiendo a http://localhost/www.youtube.com

Agregándole el protocolo si nos lleva directamente a http://www.youtube.com

Comment: Lo he hecho pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: ¿Has limpiado la caché? Yo lo he probado así a la primera y me abre en la misma ventana el enlace.

Comment: Prueba con https:// sinó no te dejará hacerlo desde StackOverflow. Además siempre que estés desarrollando tecnologías del lado del cliente recarga la página con CTRL + F5 y prueba al menos en los 3 navegadores más utilizados (Chrome, Firefox, IE/Edge). Saludos!!

Comment: @HéctorJ.OrihuelaRuiz es preferible usar `Ctrl + Shift + F5`, ya que usando `Ctrl + F5` solamente se refresca la página pero no se borra la caché de ésta.

Comment: @Javi según este enlace "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate" es ctrl + f5 (al menos es el que yo siempre usado para borrar caché, sobre todo por el tema de JS).

Comment: @HéctorJ.OrihuelaRuiz cuando enlaces archivos externos ya sean scripts, estilos o lo que sea a tu página, te darás cuenta que cuando hagas un cambio en estos archivos externos el cambio no lo apreciarás si tan solo usas `Ctrl + F5`, te dejo aquí algo que te interesará y te permitirá comprender mejor => https://stackoverflow.com/q/20569394/6817375

Comment: @Javi Tras leer y releer el enlace que me has pasado, en los comentarios y en respuestas votadas dice que CTRL + F5 hace lo mismo que Shift + F5, la página de google, hace referencia a CTRL + R pero eso no es lo que yo he propuesto. Espero que ahora sí hayas entendido bien a lo que me refería. Saludos!!

Comment: @Eduardoq: 1. Me parece que en este caso no es conveniente el uso de Stack Snippet ya que en este no se deben incluir etiquetas como `<head>` y en este caso resulta relevante, además de que `http` es bloqueado. Por tu respuesta sería mejor si incluyeras una breve explicación de porque es necesario lo que propones como solución.

Comment: @Rubén: ¡Capito!

Comment: esto se ve a leguas que es problema de configuración algún bloqueo o add ... el codigo es correcto y el html siempre se recarga lo que se guarda en cache son los archivos externos...

Comment: @Javi Buenas de nuevo, he estado investigando un poco más y ya he encontrado la diferencia entre CTRL + F5 y SHIFT + F5, la diferencia está en que CTRL limpia la Caché del navegador, mientras que SHIFT limpia la caché del proveedor de internet (ISP). Te dejo un enlace donde he podido leer esto: http://refreshyourcache.com/en/cache/   Saludos

Answer (score 2):

### Ocurre por esto

Cuando al atributo `href` del enlace se le establece `www.youtube.com` como valor de la forma `href="www.youtube.com` el navegador entiende que el enlace apunta a un directorio denominado `www.youtube.com`.

Por ejemplo, cuando queda definido así:

```html
<a href="www.youtube.com">YouTube</a>
```

Nos encontramos con un escenario parecido a esto:

```
Directorio Local
  + ../
  + index.html
  + Otro directorio/
  + www.youtube.com/
```

Si probamos el escenario anterior:

```html
<a href="www.youtube.com">YouTube</a>
```

Podemos observar que el enlace apunta a un archivo o directorio y no al sitio Web de **YouTube**. Si por el contrario, desea que el enlace apunte a un sitio Web debería definirse de la siguiente forma:

```html
<a href="//www.youtube.com">YouTube</a>
```

Donde las dos (02) barras diagonales (`//`) le indican al navegador que se quiere acceder a un sitio Web (en este caso, **YouTube**) mediante el protocolo `HTTP` o `HTTPS`.

Probemos el siguiente ejemplo:

```html
<a href="//www.youtube.com">YouTube</a>
```

Se pudo observar en el caso anterior que el enlace apunta a YouTube, pero no se muestra porque **YouTube** no permite que su sitio Web sea accesible desde un marco flotante (`iframe`). Sin embargo, sí que permite que se visualicen los vídeos embebidos.

Ejemplo de un enlace que apunta a un vídeo embebido:

```html
<a href="//www.youtube.com/embed/2JfjmWIyDfY">Batería Cuántica que nunca se agota</a>
```

Para finalizar, pruebe el ejemplo que publiqué en [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dlunamontilla/pen/MWYZZxM) para observar los resultados.